# Is there a real difference between mysqli::num_rows and mysqli::affected_rows when doing a SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been looking for a definate answer on this, but opinions on the internet slightly vary.

I am used to differentiating between using mysqli::num_rows and mysqli:affected_rows for the intended purposes. However, I read in the PHP manual that affected_rows will behave like num_rows when a select query has been executed.

My actual question is this: Is there any downside to ALWAYS using affected_rows and forgetting about num_rows? If affected_rows behaves like num_rows, what use is num_rows? Using only affected_rows would simplify my DB library code in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of operations related table records (Not table structure):

1) `Select:` When you are only fetch the data from table.

2) `Update:` When you updating the table records `(Insert/Update/Delete)` all these operations will update/change your table records.

If you run the select query the `num_rows` will work because it returns a count of rows. But when you run `Insert/Update/Delete` query `affected_rows` will work because it returns how many rows affected by your `Insert/Update/Delete` query.

Also, Mysql server returns affected rows when you run `Insert/Update/Delete` query. PHP function affected_rows convert this response directly with connection resource/object. But when you run select query mysql server returns result-set. And by using this result php function `num_rows` returns that `result set has how many rows`. For `affected_rows` we are using connection resource/object and for `num_rows` we are using `result` resource/object.

Comment: Yes, but the manual clearly states, that in the case of a select statement, affected_rows will behave like num_rows.
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: Mysql server returns affected rows when you run Insert/Update/Delete query. PHP function `affected_rows` convert this response directly with `connection` resource/object.  But when you run select query mysql server returns result-set php function and  by using this result php function `num_rows ` returns that result set has how many  rows. For `affected_rows` we are using connection resource/object and for `num_rows` we are using resource/object.

Comment: ah, wait, you are right. So, since affected_rows is not on one specific rusultset, it is unsure (to some extent) where the affected_rows is from, and using num_rows is explicitly for THAT result set.

This is indeed quite a difference, I cannot believe i missed that.... If you turn this into an answer, I can make it the accepted answer